# What is the purpose of the woven pattern on Kevlar bullet proof jackets?

Tags: material-science, carbon-fiber

The bulletproof vest is made of kevlar fiber. The fibers are woven together. I wonder why we don't use kevlar as a sheet rather than woven fibers.

Comment: What references have you found so far? Why does some body armour use plates? What about chainsaw trousers?

Comment: Chainsaw chaps have duff in them that jams the drive sprocket to stop the saw.

Comment: @PhilSweet duff? they have fibres in them - very strong maybe or maybe not kevlar but wanted to get the Op to think but maybe on a hiding to nothing...

Answer (score 1):

I rather suspect it's a matter of manufacturing ease.  Here's some [info](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-1/Bulletproof-Vest.html) describing two different bullet-resistant materials' production:

> 1 To make Kevlar, the polymer poly-para-phenylene terephthalamide must
> first be produced in the laboratory. This is done through a process
> known as polymerization, which involves combining molecules into long
> chains. The resultant crystalline liquid with polymers in the shape of
> rods is then extruded through a spinneret (a small metal plate full of
> tiny holes that looks like a shower head) to form Kevlar yarn. The
> Kevlar fiber then passes through a cooling bath to help it harden.
> After being sprayed with water, the synthetic fiber is wound onto
> rolls. The Kevlar manufacturer then typically sends the fiber to
> throwsters, who twist the yarn to make it suitable for weaving. To
> make Kevlar cloth, the yarns are woven in the simplest pattern, plain
> or tabby weave, which is merely the over and under pattern of threads
> that interlace alternatively.
>
> 2 Unlike Kevlar, the Spectra used in
> bulletproof vests is usually not woven. Instead, the strong
> polyethylene polymer filaments are spun into fibers that are then laid
> parallel to each other. Resin is used to coat the fibers, sealing them
> together to form a sheet of Spectra cloth. Two sheets of this cloth
> are then placed at right angles to one another and again bonded,
> forming a nonwoven fabric that is next sandwiched between two sheets
> of polyethylene film. The vest shape can then be cut from the
> material.

Comment: I wanted to know that Is woven/mesh structure provide more strength than sheet?

Comment: Technically, yes and no. The lateral impact energy of a projectile into Kevlar needs to be dissipated in multiple directions to maintain integrity of Kevlar material. 90° is about as effective as possible without creating multiple fiction points which could fail simultaneously.